# How can I POST a new item if "Author" hasn't been created yet?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an app to catalog records using React for the Front End and Django+REST Frameworks for the Backend. I'm using `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`, and it seems I can't create a new record unless the artist has already been created (I'll get an error letting me know `ID` field can't be `null`). I then have to include the artist and artist `ID` if I want to create a new record.

I'll copy some of my code below for reference. Thanks in advance for your help!

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(
        Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='albums')
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    acquired_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    # songs = models.ForeignKey(
    #     Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='songs')
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Song title')
    track = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(
        Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='songs')
    album = models.ForeignKey(
        Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='songs')
    song_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['album', 'track']
        ordering = ['track']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.track} - {self.title}'
```

### serializers.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import ArtistSerializer, AlbumSerializer, SongSerializer
from .models import Artist, Song, Album


class ArtistList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer


class ArtistDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer


class AlbumList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer


class AlbumDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer


class SongList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongSerializer


class SongDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongSerializer
```

Comment: If you want to create a song or album without knowing the artist, then the `artist` field should have `null=True`.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your comment! I wasn't planning on allowing the user to add albums without artists, but I do want the ability to create albums by artists that do not yet exist in the database without having to create the artist first, so ideally when creating the album the artist and both of their id's get created as well. I'm assuming this has to do with using the HyperlinkedModelSerializer, but according to the documentation using it is good RESTful practice.